# awk print vs printf functions

Tags: io, awk, printf

In `awk` there are two output functions: `print` and `printf`.

- Are their implementations in `awk` very different?
- What are the differences regarding performance/speed (if possible — theoretical, not only with "`time`" on command line)?
- Do they use the same system calls?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. The performance difference is probably not measurable.
2. The `print` function outputs a newline at the end; `printf` does not unless requested.
3. The `print` code converts the arguments to strings and then sends them to the output separated by the OFS (output field separator).
4. The `printf` code might need to convert the string to a double before formatting it using a double format (`%16.8g` or something), and similar operations.
5. The system call used is going to `write(2)` or something similar for both, but there'll be code (probably `<stdio.h>`) layered above that.

All that adds up to:

- The implementations are different; `print` is a little simpler (and therefore faster) than `printf`.
- The difference is probably not measurable for most purposes.
- Use `print` if it will do what you need; use `printf` when it does what you need.
- Don't worry about it.

And using a `sprintf` followed by `print` is likely to be slower than using `printf` directly, so don't.

In case of doubt, measure.

Comment: thank you!
I measured time for a specific output line with 3 FP parameters (many times for statistics): `print:printf ~= 16s:17s`. So the difference is realy not so big.